# Symfony2: Using a repository in a command

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony2 (2.6) and I want to use a custom repository of a Contact entity in a command whose name is CRM:fetchEmails.

I tried two different methods in order to get the repository:

First method:

In the execute function of my command file

```
$repository = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->getRepository('CRMBundle:Contact');
```

Second method:

In the execute function of my command file

```
$repository = $this->getContainer()->get('myrepository');
```

And in config.yml

```
myrepository:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
    factory: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, getRepository]
    arguments:
        - CRMBundle\Entity\Contact
```

Either with the first or second method I get this error when executing the command:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException] Notice: Undefined property: Doctrine\ORM\Configuration::$getRepository CRM:fetchEmails [name]
```

Does anyone know how to solve my problem?

Comment: Show the part where you are using fetchEmails.  Sounds like you forgot some parens

Answer (score 0):

I would inherit `ContainerAwareCommand` to solve this problem :

```
public class MyCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{ ... }
```

`ContainerAwareCommand` is a base class for Command, but has access to the container (just like you would do in a `Controller`-based class, so you can access your repo by doing `$this->getContainer()->getDoctrine()->getRepository("BundleName:MyRepo")`.

Let me know if it helps !

Comment: The error message implies the container is already available.

Answer (score 0):

From Symfony2.8 you can do this :

```
             $doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
             $em = $doctrine->getEntityManager();
             $usersRepo= $doctrine->getRepository('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User');
             $user= $usersRepo->find(1);
             $em->persist($$user);
```